# Process substitution from curl to bash as root

Tags: bash, sudo, file-descriptors, process-substitution

I'm trying to run a script from URL as root with this command:

```
sudo bash <(curl -s http://copy.com/gLVZIqUubzcS/popcorn)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
bash: /dev/fd/63: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

French for "not found". Any ideas what it might be?

P.S: I'm running Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use process substitution like that. In practice, it's pretty much just this anyway:

```
sudo sh <<CURL_SCRIPT
    $(curl -s http://copy.com/gLVZIqUubzcS/popcorn)
CURL_SCRIPT
```

Or:

```
curl -s http://copy.com/gLVZIqUubzcS/popcorn | sudo sh
```

Unless the script you're trying to run makes use of `bashisms` the above will work. If it does use `bash`-only syntax you should do:

```
curl -s http://copy.com/gLVZIqUubzcS/popcorn | sudo . /dev/stdin
```

Though the above doesn't seem to work, which I expect is due to `sudo` not liking the shell's built-in `.dot.`

So do this:

```
curl -s http://copy.com/gLVZIqUubzcS/popcorn | sudo ${0#-} /dev/stdin
```

You could also simply do:

```
sudo sh -c "$(curl -s http://copy.com/gLVZIqUubzcS/popcorn)"
```

You don't need to invoke the `bash` executable again when you can use the shell's built-ins instead.

Comment: Many thanks! Actually the script does use much of bashisms. The last method actually worked but I have to adapt my script to sh. Thanks!

Comment: @pr.nizar the `${0#-}` will work as well.

Comment: Thank you! Yep it does! Just one more question: how to pass an argument to the script with that: `sudo bash -c "$(curl -s http://copy.com/gLVZIqUubzcS/popcorn)"`? I can't figure it out!

Comment: @pr.nizar An argument to to what exactly? To the downloaded script or the subshell in which you launch it?

Comment: To the downloaded script.. If I have to pass an argument let's say `--remove`..

Comment: ${0#-} --remove "$(curl script)" ?

Comment: No. I failed to get it to work.. How to pass an argument to the downloaded script with this command: `bash -c "$(curl -s http://copy.com/gLVZIqUubzcS/popcorn)"`? I read the `man bash` but with no clues to that.. `If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.`?

Comment: @pri.nizar In that case you should use a function, and call its positionals after the script is fully loaded. Other wise you could stream in the definition on a separate file descriptor in a here-doc. Or save your params to a variable and call it afterward. Honestly, the possible solutions from my perspective are too numerous to enumerate, but that's mostly because I don't really know what you're doing. If you could specify? I'd be happy to visit any link you provide me. Perhaps in another question? Describe the workflow from start - finish and the purpose for it? And yes, that's how -c works.

Comment: Thank you very much for every answer you're giving me and for the for the effort and time! Actually the idea is to hold a script on an URL. This script is to run as root. This script reads also the arguments passed to him and there is one argument `--remove` that does a particular job. I can simply do all of this by: `wget -O popcorn http://adf.ly/jtfyQ && sudo chmod +x popcorn && sudo ./popcorn --remove` but I wanted to do that in one command and for this process substitution seamed like a good solution. (This script is intended for instance to download and install Popcorn Time last build)

Comment: @pri.nizar - this is approaching other question territory, but if you need to pass arguments then you need to configure your script to handle parameters or environment variables, or to accept arguments over stdin. Understand that because you do not `chmod +x` a file you do not `exec` the script but rather a shell that *sources* your script. This is not a very serious limitation - all shell scripts are just interpreted text files anyway - but the process is initialized a little differently and so arg handling will differ. I think the pipe would work better than than -c though.

Comment: So I believe I asked the wrong question. I'm reaching my theoric limitation of bash programming and this is an all new territory to me. I thought I'd manage arguments with this in the beginning of the script: `if [[ $# > 0 ]]; then; if [ "$1" = "--remove" ]; then; remove=1; fi; fi` then check for `$remove` elsewhere in the script `if [ $remove = 1 ]; then; dothejob; fi` but it seems as you're telling me that there are too many ways of passing arguments to a script and I must care for the way an argument is passed..?! Thank you anyway and I'll try with another question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13933/discussion-between-mikeserv-and-pr-nizar)

Answer (score 6):

`sudo` closes all open file descriptors other than stdin, stdout and stderr (see `man sudo`) so process substitution does not work OOTB with `sudo`.

Compare

```
$ sudo bash <(echo echo foo)
bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

and

```
$ bash <(echo echo foo)
foo
```

You can work around this (or use the `-C` flag to `sudo`), but doing what you are trying to do is bad - albeit common - practice anyway. If you really just want to run the installer, get a `root`-shell *first* and then run the rest without `sudo`.

Comment: Many thanks man! But it says I'm not permitted to use the -C option. I think I'm doing it wrong.. To what number should I set the fd?